# Testing secure website in Android Emulator on https://10.0.2.2

Tags: android, https, web, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to test a website in the Android Emulator. The website is required to run on HTTPS. Outside the emulator on my PC the website is running fine with SSL, because I use an official certificate which is bound to https://localhost. When I run the website in the emulator I can access in on https://10.0.2.2, but I get a warning and a red 'https' in Chrome (10.0.2.2 is the address to access localhost on the host machine).

Is there any way to get it use a certificate?

Comment: So do you have a Certificate or an self-signed ? Because chrome will allow the usages of self-signed certificates on localhost. In this case you should grab yourself an certificate von [lets-encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Answer (score 5):

A common solution is to use a tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which creates a web available HTTPS site that will proxy requests to a specific port on your local machine. Then you open `https://examplexyz.ngrok.io` in the emulator and you have a valid TLS certificate and your local development website.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome browser and others will show a warning about security when your website use a self-signed certificate. Please ignore it if you are testing at localhost. When you publish your website to production and have a domain, you can use a free SSL certificate [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: A certificate to run on localhost isn't the problem here, I've got that covered. I'm running on https://10.0.2.2 on the emulator. Which shows a message the site is dangerous... Going to try a self signed certificate...

Comment: Because on the emulator, your self-signed certificate wasn't installed.